# How to compare two arrays in python, and get the boolean output based on a significant value

Tags: python, arrays, compare

I am doing classification. I have two arrays, the first is 'Actual', and the second is 'Predicted'. I want to compare these two arrays. Suppose the first array is:

```
Actual = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

this tells us that the the first, second, and the last indexes are corresponding to class *1*.

The 'Predicted' array is:

```
Predicted = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3]
```

this tells us that the first and second indexes have been predicted accurately.

If you see the predicted array, the first and second arrays have been accurately predicted, but the fifth value of label *1* has not been accurately predicted. 
I want the output the tells us just those indexes that accurately predicted as *1*, and those not. like this:

```
output = [True, True, False]
```

by this output, we know that two labels of *1* have been predicted accurately, and one label has not been accurately.

**Update**
I want to evaluate just based on value *1*. If you see, the forth predicted value is accurately predicted by *3*, but I do not want that, because I want evaluate *1* value.

Comment: You just need the true and false, not the actual indexes?

Comment: What's the expected result for `A = [2, 2, 3, 4, 2]` and `P = [2, 2, 2, 4, 4]`? And what for `A = [1, 2, 3]` and `P = [1, 2, 3]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to `True` and `False` values only, you can still use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function and list comprehension as below -

```
>>> Actual = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1]
>>> Predicted = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3]
>>> output = [a == p for a,p in zip(Actual,Predicted) if p==1]
>>> output
[True, True, False]
```

Explanation - This would take all the elements where `Predicted` has value 1. And then the output list would contain whether those values are same in `Actual` or not.

Please note - `zip` would only take elements till the shortest list. But I am guessing that is not an issue in your case.

Comment: Are you sure? In [True, True, False] the False comes from comparing 3 with 3, not 3 with 1 (i.e. the last values,  driven by 1)

Comment: Try [p == a for a,p in zip(Actual,Predicted) if a==1]

Comment: Yea thanks, I read it a little wrong, I thought the question was to show the values, that got accurately predicted but were not 1. Thanks corrected.